# Dockerfile: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, .net-core

When trying to containerize my app and `docker build -t vendor/name:1.0 .`, I receive the following error:
`failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu/dotnet-aspnet:7.0-22.10_edge

COPY . .

RUN dotnet publish "./RaspCronJobServer/RaspCronJobServer.csproj" -o /application

WORKDIR /application

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "RaspCronJobServer.dll" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your base image(`ubuntu/dotnet-aspnet:7.0-22.10_edge`) does not have `/bin/sh`. Docker put `/bin/sh` before running RUN:

```bash
/bin/sh dotnet publish "./RaspCronJobServer/RaspCronJobServer.csproj" -o /application
```

That is why you got that error.

You could change your base image that have `/bin/sh`.

Comment: I can't find any information about it missing /bin/sh ? It is a Ubuntu based distro so should definitely have sh as well as bash.

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/layers/ubuntu/dotnet-aspnet/7.0-22.10_edge/images/sha256-84bcd467da2b5d69e80318aee42674e9a282a328101dfcadfc95942a52c0faa2?context=explore. This is the `Dockerfile`. It is not based on ubuntu.

Comment: See https://hub.docker.com/r/ubuntu/dotnet-aspnet which I've also tried, and it is based on Ubuntu. I don't think image choice is the issue here.

Comment: Which tag have you tried?

Comment: I'm trying 7.0, although `ubuntu:22.10` and installing dotnet 7 on top works, not ideal though.