# Containerize .NET 7.0 Console AND ASP.NET application with Docker?

Tags: c#, .net, docker

I'm a little stuck, I have a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75863970/dockerfile-unable-to-start-container-process-exec-bin-sh-stat-bin-sh-no/75864446#75864446) which is around missing /bin/sh in Docker containers. I'm looking for the correct docker image for .NET 7.0 on LINUX that can host a Console Application with an embedded ASP.NET OWIN web server, do I need to make a custom one here? None of them seem to have /bin/sh?

Error: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu/dotnet-aspnet:7.0-22.10_edge

COPY . .

RUN dotnet publish "./RaspCronJobServer/RaspCronJobServer.csproj" -o /application

WORKDIR /application

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "RaspCronJobServer.dll" ]
```

Comment: Why do you need OWIN?

Comment: I think my technology choices is irrelevant to how to deploy my app to docker, but I use OWIN for embedding a web server into my app.

Comment: Precisely - you don't need OWIN at all. ASP.NET Core has its own web server, Kestrel. If you create a new web app with `dotnet new webapi` or `dotnet new mvc` (or any of the other templates) you get an application that can run on Linux directly and uses middleware for routing, CORS etc. You can use template arguments to add various types of authentication or you can configure it in code.

Comment: In fact, you can publish the ASP.NET Core app [directly into a container](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-builtin-container-support-for-the-dotnet-sdk/) instead of an executable, eg `dotnet publish --os linux --arch x64 -c Release -p:PublishProfile=DefaultContainer`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand that... but this isn't the issue in focus. The question is, how do I publish and run the app via Docker, not my choices in how to include a web server.

Comment: I already answered that. That's the out-of-the-box behavior so what's the actual problem? ASP.NET Core apps are console apps. And they can be published directly to Docker images. Even if you don't want that, you need nothing special to build and package them, just use the Dockerfile shown in the docs to build the image. Your Dockerfile has no build step though

Comment: My question is which docker image do I need, because the one I've selected doesn't seem to even have the base commands needed such as `/bin/sh`, also I believe publishing also builds, as read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57839914/21375633 - every answer I come across assumes I want Windows.

Comment: Did you [check the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-dockerfile)? `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0` for the build step, `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0` for the runtime image. Or, as I already posted, just `dotnet publish ... -p:PublishProfile=DefaultContainer` to get rid of the Dockerfile completely

Comment: `every answer I come across assumes I want Windows` that's why you should read the documentation first.

Comment: What is using `bins/sh`? AFAIK default shell on Ubuntu is `bash`. `bin/sh` if present usually should be a symbolic link to it according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/141932/1162791)

Comment: The Ubuntu image you're using is very stripped down, compared to the Microsoft images and it doesn't have a shell. If you need a shell, you can use the Microsoft images instead, like others have suggested.

Comment: Microsoft *does* support stripped down [Chiseled Ubuntu](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-6-is-now-in-ubuntu-2204/#net-in-chiseled-ubuntu-containers) images too, supported by Canonical. The question didn't ask about that though.

Comment: @ashdevelops is the *real* question how to package the web app using Chiseled Ubuntu? `dotnet-aspnet:7.0-22.10_edge` seems to be the name of a specific Chiseled image. That's very different from publishing a Linux image.

Comment: @ashdevelops the blog post announcing Chiseled Ubuntu images has a section on [Using Chiseled Container Images](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-6-is-now-in-ubuntu-2204/#using-chiseled-container-images). You cant' just use them by themselves - there's no distro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the real question is how to use [Chiseled Ubuntu container](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-6-is-now-in-ubuntu-2204/#using-chiseled-container-images) images. `dotnet-aspnet:7.0-22.10_edge` is the name of a Chiseled image, not a regular image.

As the linked blog post explains, these are essentially distroless images, stripped down to the very basics. There's no shell or anything not directly needed by the application itself. Building the application still requires a regular SDK image but the final target will be a `chiseled` image.

From the [Using Chiseled Container Images](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-6-is-now-in-ubuntu-2204/#using-chiseled-container-images) example, the Dockerfile should look like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0-jammy AS build
WORKDIR /source

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore --use-current-runtime

# copy and publish app and libraries
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app --use-current-runtime --self-contained false --no-restore

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/runtime:7.0-jammy-chiseled
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dotnetapp.dll"]
```

This builds the app normally but packages it in a Chiseled image instead of the normal `runtime` image.

---

**Original Answer**

Short Version: You can already publish an ASP.NET Core 7 web app directly to Docker :

```
dotnet publish --os linux --arch x64 -c Release -p:PublishProfile=DefaultContainer
```

---

ASP.NET Core doesn't need OWIN, it uses its own middleware pipelines and provides everything that OWIN did. I'm not sure if it *can* use OWIN, or it will interfere with ASP.NET Core.

ASP.NET Core applications *are* console applications too, so the problem is solved out of the box. They can be packaged into Docker images easily. The ASP.NET Core [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-dockerfile) shows how to manually add a Dockerfile to build and package the web app but that can also be done [using project template settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/hosting-web-apps-in-docker?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-7.0).

The Dockerfile builds the application using the SDK image and copies the output to a new image based on the Runtime image. This ensures the final image is as small as possible:

```
# https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY aspnetapp/*.csproj ./aspnetapp/
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY aspnetapp/. ./aspnetapp/
WORKDIR /source/aspnetapp
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app --no-restore

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

The actual publishing command is `dotnet publish -c release -o /app --no-restore`. You could create a single file executable if you wanted, but since you use a container it's fine to use `dotnet aspnetapp.dll` to run the web app.

**Publish direct to Docker**

.NET 7 can [publish directly to Docker images](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-builtin-container-support-for-the-dotnet-sdk/), eliminating the Dockerfile. You can do what you want with a single profile switch.

From the blog example, you can create an MVC app with

```
# create a new project and move to its directory
dotnet new mvc -n my-awesome-container-app
cd my-awesome-container-app

# add a reference to a (temporary) package that creates the container
dotnet add package Microsoft.NET.Build.Containers
```

And publish it to Docker with

```
# publish your project for linux-x64
dotnet publish --os linux --arch x64 -c Release -p:PublishProfile=DefaultContainer
```

Comment: _"I'm not sure if it can use OWIN"_ - according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/owin?view=aspnetcore-7.0) you can. Though personally I don't why somebody would (except for migrating the old app) =)

Comment: That page doesn't explain what gremlins may be encountered but it does show that adding OWIN has no effect on the web app itself - it's another middleware.